# mysql query to count the age from the dob in m/d/y format withim mysql query

Tags: mysql

i am making a query to get the age of the user which is stored in `d/m/y` in database . for that i have tired to make the following query

```
select *,TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, dob, now()) as age_new from users_profile
```

but it does not seems to work and return the value as `NULL` . the dob for eg is like `12/5/1990` so i wanted to calculate the age within the results . Like it would make a new column and display the count result inside  `new_age`

Comment: what is the type of dob? date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As your `dob` field is not in `date` or `datetime` format. We need to convert it.

Here is the query which worked fine for me.

`SELECT YEAR(FROM_DAYS(DATEDIFF(NOW(), STR_TO_DATE('12/5/1990', '%d/%m/%Y')))) AS age_new`

or your query will be:

`SELECT YEAR(FROM_DAYS(DATEDIFF(NOW(), STR_TO_DATE(dob, '%d/%m/%Y')))) AS age_new from users_profile`

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
select *, YEAR(FROM_DAYS(DATEDIFF(NOW(), dob))) as age_new from users_profile
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select *, 
DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y') - DATE_FORMAT(dob, '%Y') - (DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '00-%m-%d') < DATE_FORMAT(dob, '00-%m-%d')) as age_new from users_profile
```

It looks like either `dob` is not `date` type or mysql is not able to read its format.

Answer (score 0):

Below query works for me:

```
SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(YEAR, '1983/12/5', CURRENT_DATE()) AS AGE
```